# How to troubleshoot "File not found (removed)" in UI

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I'm trying to correct the data types of some columns in my csv file before pushing it to Big query. No matter how I run it I end up with:

**File not found (removed): The file gs://bucketshahtest/*****/********.csv could not be found. It may have been removed while initializing the Dataflow job. Please verify that the source file is still available and re-run the job.**

(Hidden the file names for the sake of this being a public forum)

I've tried changing the export file name, trying renaming the source file as well as changing whether to export to Google Cloud Storage or BigQuery

I'm doing this to eventually be able to ingest the files into Google Big Query so that I can process them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear if you're experiencing this error when you're creating the job or running it (you may want to update the original question to clarify).

**I see a few possibilities:**

1. The data you see when working in the Dataprep interface is sampled. It's possible that the underlying file has been deleted, but you still see the sample.  This could be due to an expiration policy on the storage bucket/folder, or manual action. You could also check this by selecting the dataset, choosing "Replace", and re-importing the file from Cloud Storage.
2. Check that the input file exists in the [Cloud Storage browser interface](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser). Pay special attention to letter case and punctuation. Also keep in mind that file paths containing multiple slashes (e.g. "test//file.csv) will have them flattened to a single slash in this context (so set your URL accordingly). Also ensure that there's no trailing slash *after* the filename.  When possible, it's best to pick the file from the built-in storage browser on the Import or Replace screens to avoid issues.
3. It's also possible that Dataprep doesn't have the correct permissions to read from the Cloud Storage bucket or folder. Ensure that you're reading from the same project, and that the setup steps for Dataprep have been followed.  You may want to double-check that you've completed all of the steps from the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-dataprep), including enabling the Cloud Storage API. Also, here are some additional details on [using Dataprep with Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Using-Google-Cloud-Storage_59736094)

You definitely want to use a different filename for the export (or import directly to BigQuery).  Also make sure you don't have an output in the job settings that overwrites the file AND one that exports to BigQuery . . . this would also explain it failing (since it would likely overwrite the file it's trying to read from). In general, you don't want to write output files to the default Uploads folder or to Dataprep's temporary directories.

If you continue to have issues, you could try uploading the file through the Import dialog and seeing if it throws an error creating it in Cloud Storage, which would indicate a permissions issue.

If all else fails, I would create a new Flow and recreate the dataset and recipe there to test and eliminate any artifacts from an earlier issue.

Update: Also worth checking that the Cloud Storage object conforms to their [object naming guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming#objectnames)

Comment: Thanks for the great reply! Gave me thoughts for other ways to troubleshoot things in the future. This time though the solution turns out to be much simpler. I was trying to preserve the [ ] in the file name while renaming it as it conveys some important information. But turns out Cloud Data Prep doesn't like that in the file name. Removed then and zip zap zoom it started working.

Comment: @KshitijShah Out of curiosity, did you select the file through the Cloud Storage Browser in Dataprep, or did you paste the path in manually? If it was selected through the browser, it should have escaped any special characters (and a bug should be filed to correct that).

Comment: I did select it through the browser